# How to get the change event of a layer in OL3 using ol.control.LayerSwitcher

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers 3 with the [ol.control.LayerSwitcher](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher) plugin and wanted to know how I can get it when I change a layer on the switcher. I was searching a lot on the internet and I can not find a solution to this. 
The idea is to change a layer using the ol.control.LayerSwitcher plugin to perform an action such as an alert.

If someone could give me a help or an alternative to this. If you know of another alternative that does not use ol.control.LayerSwitcher and determine the change event of a specific layer, I would like to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the answer and the solution is:

```
var layer_country = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: 'Countries',
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'ne:ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines_shp'},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
});
// Evento change del layer layer_country.
layer_country.on('change:visible', function(){
    alert("Countries");
});
```

[Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42857/como-obtener-el-evento-change-de-un-layer-en-ol3-usando-ol-control-layerswitcher)